# Can you replace "anywhere" with "where"?

Tags: word-difference, relative-adverbs

For example:

"I don't have anywhere to put them" becomes "I don't have where to put them".

This doesn't make sense to me but apparently, according to my girlfriend, is also correct.

Comment: Some of the usages certainly overlap (I can't see where / anywhere to put them), but this sounds non-standard to my ears. There _are_ some examples of the 'where' example on the internet, though. But none on a Google Ngram search.

Comment: That example is definitely wrong; you can't use _where_ in that sentence.

Comment: @SomethingDark Your authority for such a claim? Note that 'I've never heard it used' is insufficient.

Comment: While there are constructions where either could be used, the meanings are different.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - _where_ is a [relative adverb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/where), not a noun. _Anywhere_, on the other hand, [can be a pronoun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anywhere).

Comment: Using where would not work because it is not a pronoun

Comment: @SomethingDark Better, but there are examples of 'where' being used as what might be analysed as a pronoun after 'have' in a few places on the internet. I think it might be an archaic usage, but a check in OED is probably required. 'I can't find where to put them' and 'I can't find anywhere to put them' are both idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth idiomatic or not your two sentences don't mean the same. The first means 'I can't find **the** place to put them', and the second means 'I can't find **a** place to put them'. Thus pronoun or not, your argument only illustrates that the two words are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Born2Smile Agreed, but notice that I'm not answering here. I'm addressing the claims in comments above 'you can't use _where_ in that sentence' ... 'using _where_ would not work because it is not a pronoun'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ah, but you did answer. Regardless of intent. The original poster didn't care about the pronoun state of the two words, but about whether the two words were interchangeable. And you have illustrated with example that indeed they are not. Problem solved, question answered, thumbs up :)

Comment: Can your girlfriend cite a single attestation?

Comment: I see how "I *can't find* where to put them" would make sense if you are talking about a specific place. I was wondering whether it is grammatically correct, even if the meaning is slightly different. Sorry for that confusion.

Comment: Analogously, "I don't have anything to do" vs "I don't have what to do" is another one she claims to be correct.

Comment: @Born2Smile It's a far from complete answer, and so I'm not posting it as an 'answer'. And I'd say that the two words cannot without further study be considered 'totally non-interchangeable' when internet examples such as '[S]o numerous is this family, that should they all happen at once to make a rush with their offerings, they might not have where to put them.' exist. Note that this is the exact construction; hereabouts, even a slight change might affect acceptability. (I still consider this example unidiomatic to unacceptable nowadays.) ...

Comment: The above quote from [Christian Spectator, Vol III, 1821](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Qx09AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA350&lpg=PA350&dq=%22have+where+to+put+them%22&source=bl&ots=7rpeLP-0YI&sig=TfGQnKKahrHHan9BtpRHxb6uws0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF66DtlbLLAhXKuhQKHYxJAxAQ6AEIKDAD#v=onepage&q=%22have%20where%20to%20put%20them%22&f=false).

Comment: Whether or not these constructions ("I don't have where to put them". /  "I don't have what to do.") should be, or are, considered 'correct' depends on the standard you adopt to measure 'correctness'. I'd say that they are non-standard usages, probably quite acceptable in some dialects. And I'd avoid them unless I was sure that they would sound normal to my audience, or unless I was deliberately trying to sound odd.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree with your comments here. The pronoun form definitely sounds idiomatic, albeit anciently, to me - *he hath not where to lay his head* - keeps ringing in my ears. But I have been through the entire OED entry and cannot find any example. But when you think about it *anywhere* must have begun as *any where* .

Comment: Considering your nym, your girlfriend has put a hex on you with her non-idiomatic claim.  Dump her.

Comment: @WS2 Yes; the examples I've come across on the internet seem to be  either Christian commentaries etc (probably cherishing the AV usage) or recent examples containing other non-standard usages..Your point about 'any where' is almost certainly a valid factor. But thank you for wading through the OED (not my favourite, as you know, but best for historic developments).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Eureka! We cracked it - Luke 9:58 *And Jesus said unto him, Foxes have holes, and birds of the air have nests; but the Son of man hath not where to lay his head.* It is in the AV. Now why hasn't the OED got it?

Comment: I'll add a reference from two different versions of the Bible to show the possibility of interchangeability: {[BibleHub.com](http://biblehub.com/luke/9-58.htm)}:  Luke 9:58 

**New American Standard Bible**  
And Jesus said to him, "The foxes have holes and the birds of the air have nests, but the Son of Man has nowhere to lay His head."

**King James Bible** 
And Jesus said unto him, Foxes have holes, and birds of the air have nests; but the Son of man hath not where to lay his head. >> However, I'd not recommend that one use the KJV either as one's main Bible or as a style guide.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you should supply it as an answer - since it was you who jogged my mind with reference to the AV (or KJV as the Americans call it)..

Comment: @WS2 The title question is far more general than the example given. And the real answer to the limited question is 'Not since 1650, unless you live in XYZ or want to sound distinctly odd.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nothing wrong with speaking 17th century English. There are Societies which arrange weekends where everyone dresses in period costume and speak only in Shakespearean English. I would love to have the skill.

Comment: This example is also cited in [*Picket's Grammar*](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=flEhAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=%22not+where+to+lay+his+head%22+grammar&source=bl&ots=-9zDEy01UA&sig=unaqrSkRohosKBdmCV9h-q8lcsg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQtpO34sjLAhXiG6YKHSDDAPYQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=%22not%20where%20to%20lay%20his%20head%22%20grammar&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

It is an ancient form, found *inter alia* in the Authorised Version (1611) of the Bible (otherwise known as the King James Version):

> And Jesus said unto him, Foxes have holes, and birds of the air have nests; but the Son of man hath not where to lay his head. (Luke 9:58)

Comment: That's clearly a precursor to *nowhere*, not *anywhere*!

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not interchangeable. In the second sentence you could say... I don't know where to put them. But that certainly has a different meaning.

Comment: Please take the site [tour] and review the [help]. It is not enough to say "yes" or "no"; you must explain *why* you hold your position, else the post is not an answer so much as personal opinion, and may be downvoted as such.

Answer (score 0):

No, since "where" is typically used singularly ("Where did you go?" "He went where?") and "anywhere" is typically used in a plural sense ("I can't find it anywhere", "Just leave it anywhere"). If you have multiples but a definite location you would typically use "where." If you know I went to Europe, but wanted to know what countries I visited, you would still ask "Where did you go in Europe?" If you have no idea one way or the other about whether I took a trip at all, you would instead ask "Did you go anywhere this summer?" In that example, there is no definite location, while in the others there is.

There may be a slightly better way to phrase it, but that's about all I can squeeze out of my brain at the moment. Sorry if it's not precise enough.